How do I manage the version names of docker images in a gitlab CI?
I have a situation where I am building the back end of an application using kubernetes, helm and a gitlab CI.
To make things simple, I will say that I have two images that get built in the CI, I will be calling them A and B. Since building them takes time, I need to only build them when needed. I am struggling to understand how I can properly tag the built images in a way that allows kubernetes to use the latest consistently.
The issue is as follows :
If I update just the code in the image of A, I want to build image A and leave image B untouched.
If I use $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA in the name, I'll have no issues making sure that the latest image of A is being used by helm but it is not going to find B as that version was not built.
I do have a latest tag in my CI but I noticed that kubernetes will consider that it already has an image with that tag and proceed to not download the latest latest.
Currently I have a solution where I am using a version.txt file that contains the version number. It works well as it allows everything to be synchronised but it requires manual input and in turn can cause errors. Ideally I am looking for something that is fully automated.
Is there a naming convention, tools and / or good practices that allow to solve this issue ?

Refer to the similar SO for more information.

The latest tag is applied to the most recent docker build or docker tag command that was run without a tag value explicitly set. Therefore, it's possible to run docker commands out of order or to explicitly set tags on some images. Both scenarios cause the latest tag to refer to a build that isn't the most recent and It doesn't actually mean that docker will pull the most recent version of the container. Also refer to this medium blog by Marc Campbell.
The Version.txt is needed to manually update the version number for every build. Instead of using Version.txt try Build server versioning, it's the auto updating version number.
Build server versioning build server to manage version numbers. Version number is a build number which is automatically incremented with every build. Storage of the version number is done via version.txt, or it may be something internal to the build server.
Note : Dynamic tags with GitLab CI variables offer a simple and flexible solution. Use tools like SemVer and also use a container registry like Docker Hub or a private registry for image storage.
